# minimum of $F(z) = 4\left|z-1-2i\right|^2+13\left|z-4-5i\right|^2+12\left|z-2-7i\right|^2+23\left|z-6i\right|^2$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find Minimum value of
>
> $F(z) = 4\left|z-1-2i\right|^2+13\left|z-4-5i\right|^2+12\left|z-2-7i\right|^2+23\left|z-6i\right|^2$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Put $z=x+iy\;,$ We get $$f(x,y) = 4(x-1)^2+4(y-2)^2+13(x-4)^2+13(y-5)^2+12(x-2)^2+12(y-7)^2+23x^2+23(y-6)^2$$

Now after expanding and form complete square in $x$ and $y$ get $\min(f(x,y))$

my question is can we solve it some shorter way, if yes then plz explain here, Thanks

Comment: this is pretty short as we can take $x$ and $y$ part independently , giving us two quadratic equations to minimize

Comment: In probability terms you are trying to find a point which minimizes the variance of the squared distances to a collection of points. That is well known to be the mean, so you just find the mean of the points $1+2i$ etc weighted by 4, 13 etc. But that is exactly the same process as minimizing the two quadratics. Either way you end up with $\frac{20}{13}+i\frac{295}{52}$ and $\frac{11459}{52}$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be thought of as a centre of mass style question. 
First recall $|z-a|$ is the distance between $z$ and $a$. Now $F(z)$ is a weighted average of such distances. Now the minimum of this weighted average will correspond to the centre of mass of the system: 
4 at $(1,2)$, 13 at $(4,5)$, 12 at $(2,7)$ and 23 at $(0,6)$ 

EDIT: $F(z)$ is a wieghted average of squared distances so this analogy doesn't quite work. Can anyone adjust this to something correct?

Comment: So are you saying that the cm is the minimizing point, or are you saying it would be nice if someone else answered the question? :)

Comment: If the moduli where not squared, the minimum would be the centre of mass of that system. But as they are squared, I am not sure how the analogy can be adjusted to correct for this. I was hoping for a similar idea to your probability variance but in the context of mechanics/geometry.